# How can I tweak the behavior or size of Core Data's default cache?

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

Core Data has built-in caching mechanism and uses it automatically for object fetching and faulting-related operations, but I couldn't find any documents or articles about modifying this default caching behaviors.
Is there any way to increase or decrease Core Data's default cache?
I'm considering of making a kind of `NSManagedObject` container in order to reduce overheads of loading data from persistent store, but not sure it's a good idea or not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, CoreData does not expose any general API to control its caching behavior.
You can control the size of the object graph of a given context by using:

```
[context refreshObject:<obj> mergeChanges:NO];
```

or by reseting the context entirely:

```
[context reset];
```

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW4) for more information.
[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW3) might also be of interest.

The container you plan to build sounds like the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` which is the one keeping the cache/snapshots for the objects, or the registered objects in a given `NSManagedObjectContext`.

In my opinion, there is no reason to "roll your own" cache for CoreData, as this is exactly what you get for free by using the framework.
Your container will have to keep objects keyed by context (an object cannot be shared between contexts) and object ID, so the effect will be the same as calling `[context objectRegisteredForID:<objectID>];` or the other methods that access the context current existing objects.

There is a need for a container in a case where you need transient properties to be transferred between contexts and it is costly to recalculate them or obtain their value from scratch.